# Why do I get Page Not Found (404) when using path() instead of url()?

Tags: python, html, django

I am working a new Django app following a YouTube tutorial, and so far in my 'urls.py' I've used this code:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),]
```

and it just worked. However, now I've reached a point where I'm making subdomains (localhost:8000/accounts/register) and using the following code:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('register', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

gives me the following error:

[image: Page not found error image (imgur)]

However, when instead of using `path()` I use `url()`, like so:

```
urlpatterns = [
url('register', views.register, name='register')]
```

it works as expected.

What is the difference between path() and url(), and which one should I use (in general or in any specific cases)?
Thank you for your help guys, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You forgot a slash in your `path(..)`. It should be `path('register/', views.register, name='register'),`.

Comment: This worked! However, going to localhost:8000/accounts/register.html still didn't work, but going to localhost:8000/accounts/register did. Turns out I also had to remove the .html extension from my index.html file.