# Django / HTML Submit button redirecting to the wrong page

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to make a registration form with Django & HTML and I am following this tutorial: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTmQOjsl0eg)

2:45:00 into the video, I do the exact same steps as him, even though the only difference in my code is related to my previous question: 
[My previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58546598/why-do-i-get-page-not-found-404-when-using-path-instead-of-url?noredirect=1#comment103414122_58546598)

This is my HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="register" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
        <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Password"><br>
        <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password"><br>
        <input type="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth

def register(request):

    if (request.method == 'post'):
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        email = request.POST['email']

        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password1, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
        user.save()
        print('user created')
        return redirect('')

    else:
        return render(request, 'register.html')
```

However, it seems that when I press "Submit", instead of the button actually reading the views.py code and check the IF statement, it just redirects me to localhost:8000/account/register/register, which is completely wrong, such as shown here: [Imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afCwA.png)

I am unsure of what I am doing wrong, and why my code is acting differently even though I am doing exactly what the tutorial guy is doing in his video?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His code is simply wrong. You can't just put a view name in the `action` attribute like that; it needs to be an actual path. Since your URL is "/account/register", that's what you should use.

But a decent tutorial would have introduced the `{% url %}` tag. And, in fact, a decent tutorial would have used Django forms here; he seems to have completely neglected to think about validation, which is pretty inexcusable. I'd recommend finding a different tutorial.

(Note, you've made errors yourself in copying his code; in the view where you check `request.method` it must be "POST", not "post".)

Comment: Thank you Daniel, this seemed to work, though I had to change it to "/accounts/register/" with that "/" at the end, because otherwise I got "You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set."

Quick question, should I set APPEND_SLASH to True or False? Which is better practice?

And on the other note, could you please be kind enough to recommend me easy to follow beginner Django tutorials, but ones that get to the point and do stuff like designing registration/login forms like this one.

I would really appreciate it as I'm just starting out.